# Using grep to find string with brackets

Tags: unix, grep

I have some problems with the grep command. I have the following two files in my folder:

test.dat:

```
fdf
bla(fd_bla_bla) =&
bdf bla
```

test2.dat

```
fd
fd
fij
d
bla(fdf)

fdjk
bla
```

Now I search for the bla having brackets after it with

```
grep 'bla(*)' *
```

but it just gives me the entry of the first file...Do you have an idea why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need regular expressions to do that match.

```
egrep "bla\(.*\)" *.dat
```

will give the correct result.

Answer (score 5):

your `grep 'bla(*)' *` won't work, because it looks for `bla)` or `bla(((((((()` that is , 0 or many `(` after `bla` then followed by single `)`

just do:

```
grep '\bbla(' *.dat
```

- by default grep uses BRE, so `(` in pattern would match literal `(`
- the `\b` (word boundary)  will make grep match `foo bla(..)` and `bla(xx)`, but not `foobla(xxx)`.

Comment: @Guiste if you don't need the `\b`, `grep 'bla('` would work too

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -F "bla("
```

This will tell grep to use special characters as a regular (Fixed) string.

Answer (score 3):

**You just need `.*` instead of `*`**

In Regex `.*` matched any arbitrary string of 0 or more length. `*` is used by shell GLOB to match a text of arbitrary search but `grep` doesn't use `GLOB`.

```
grep 'bla(.*)' *.dat
```

**OR for word boundaries:**

```
grep '\<bla(.*)' *.dat
```

**OR using awk:**

```
awk '/bla\(.*\)/{print FILENAME ":" $0}' *.dat
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is that, if your string is fixed string and it contains brackets. so with the help of grep -F you can make your string fixed and it will be search as it is.
    `cat enb.txt | grep -F '[PHY][I]UE'`** 
cat enb.txt is the file name where i want to catch.
`grep -F  '[PHY][I]UE'`   grep -F make the string this `'[PHY][I]UE'`   Fixed.

try this i hope it will work

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne 'print if(/bla\(.*\)/)' your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep "bla(" *
```

should work. ( need not be escaped as it indicates grouping in regex which we don't need it .

```
$ cat > test7
fdf
bla(fd_bla_bla) =&
bdf bla


$ cat > test8
fd
fd
fij
d
bla(fdf)

fdjk
bla

$ grep "bla(" *
test7:bla(fd_bla_bla) =&
test8:bla(fdf)
```